# How to get custom virtual keyboard in android?

Tags: android

I need to get virtual keyboard like that contains all  numbers
maybe through android:keyboard

i also need a keyboard that contains all alphabets only

Comment: What do you mean with "you need"? You want to implement a custom keyboard? Or do you want to force the user only to be able to insert numbers into a text field?

Comment: https://github.com/gaara87/Android-CustomNumpad
its very basic and can be worked on for customization

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as i know, there is no "only alphabet" keyboard is available using `android:keyboard`. But what you can do is

1) Restrict input of numbers by manually putting a validation in your edittext field.
2) You can create your own virtual keyboard. This [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=input) contains some information for the purpose.

Comment: page not found on provided link.